# Directive that inserts code before and after self

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am just getting used to doing things the "angular" way, so please excuse if I break some major rules or best practices.

I am trying to generate a directive to have an input field with an icon on the right side to clear its contents.

I would want to write in HTML:

```
<input clearable-input ng-model="name">
```

I tried to use a directive like so:

```
Directives.directive("clearableInput", function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
      scope: false,
      replace:    false,
      transclude: false,
      restrict:    "A",

      link: function( scope, element, attrs, controller){

        var pre = "<span style='position: relative;'>" +
              "  <span style='padding-right: 16px; width: 100%;' ng-transclude>";

        var post ="  </span>" +
          "  <span class='clickToClear' style=\"position: absolute; display: block; top: -2px; right: 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px; background: url('Images/sprites.png') 0 -690px; cursor: pointer;\" ng-click=''></span>" +
          "</span>";

              element.insertBefore(pre);
              element.insertAfter(post);

              element.find("span.clickToClear").on( "click", function(){
        var parsed = $parse(attrs["clearableInput"]);
        if( parsed.assign ) {
          parsed.assign( scope, "");
        }
        scope.$digest();
      });
  }
};
```

});

This does not work as expected at all. 
All I have come up with is to wrap a  around the input which has the "clearable-input" attribute. Then I can work with "replace: true" and "transclude: true" and I am able to use the input field I have in the html.

Did anyone create a directive which adds code before and after itself?

Thanks for your help.

Andreas

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `ng-tranclude` correctly. I have tried to emulate your scenario in this fiddle. Have a [look](http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/xE32r/)

Basically you need to create a template, and add the `ng-transclude` there. Not in link function.

Comment: Maybe I did not write it down very clear, sorry.

The problem is that I can only use transclude for the child-elements of the element that I defined the directive on. 

My target was to have:

    <input clearable-input ng-model="xyz">

Currently I can only use transclude if I put a tag around the input like so: 

    <span clearable-input>
      <input ng-model="xyz>
    </span>

This does work, but it is not quite what I am searching for, as I have to put a tag on the parent to have some behaviour on a client.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Directive child html is replace not,the  directive html node.